# How do password manager apps detect input tags?

Tags: web-crawlers, users, password

How? Does it scrape the website for adjacent input tags, one with text and one with password? No matter which website I visit, it accurately prompts a dropdown (Touch ID on Safari) on the username field. How can I build something similar?

Comment: I believe the `type` attribute, e.g. `<input type="password">`, is the most important part. Check [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password).

Answer (score 0):

HTML for a name field maybe

```html
        <label for='idName' class="required">Your name</label>
          <input type='text' name='inpName' id='idName' class='full_width'
           maxlength='60' autocomplete='username' value=''>
```

It is the `autocomplete` attribute that does the magic.

Some values are

- username
- current-password
- email
- tel

[See Here for a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

You can use other attributes such as `name` and `id` as well.

Comment: I don't think so.  Many sites that have password managers trigger don't use "autocomplete" - some of mine included.

Comment: @Steve, my experience is different. And I did say that you can use other attributes.

Comment: I don't understand why @RohitGupta gets downvoted because he is right. More info on how password managers like LastPass, 1Password etc detect and autofill input fields can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form and here https://hidde.blog/making-password-managers-play-ball-with-your-login-form/

Comment: @Maurice, I assume it was Steve, and it's his prerogative to downvote.